# Powershell script error when reading JSON file

Tags: powershell, ps1

Im running this piece of code in powershell

```
 $url = "https://someURL/file.json"
$json = (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString($url)

$data = $json | ConvertFrom-Json

$data | ConvertTo-Json -depth 100 | Out-File "C:\scripts\LW\data.json"
```

but when I run it I got this error:
**the length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxjsonlength property powershell**

[image]

Any solution for this ?

Comment: How big is `file.json`? Max json input length (in 5.1 at least) is `[int]::MaxValue` bytes, so ~2GB

Comment: it's 21 MB size

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a complete explanation, because I cannot reproduce the symptom,<sup>[1]</sup> but what seems to be happening is:

- In *Windows PowerShell* (whose latest and *last* version is v5.1), `ConvertFrom-Json` uses the (deprecated) [`System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer) .NET class.
- An instance of this class (if directly constructed, which `ConvertFrom-Json` must do) has a limit on the "maximum length of JSON strings", reflected in its [`MaxJsonLength`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.maxjsonlength) property whose default value is "2097152 characters, which is equivalent to 4 MB of Unicode string data."
- It is unclear whether `ConvertFrom-Json` uses this default or sets a different value, but you seem to have run into the effective limit, and `ConvertFrom-Json` does *not* expose a way to *increase* that limit.

  - However, in Windows PowerShell v5.1 *no* artificial limit is imposed,<sup>[2]</sup> given that `ConvertFrom-Json` there seemingly can even handle *.NET strings of maximum length*.<sup>[1]</sup>

Therefore, you may have to find a *different* way to parse your JSON data; per the recommendations in the [`JavaScriptSerializer` docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer), there are at least two options (v5.1 PowerShell versions now build on .NET Framework v4.8):

> For .NET Framework 4.7.2 and later versions, use the APIs in the [`System.Text.Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json) namespace for serialization and deserialization.
> For earlier versions of .NET Framework, use [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json).

[Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) is actually what underlies the [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) implementation of `ConvertFrom-Json`, though a move to [`System.Text.Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json) has at least been contemplated, but a PR to that effect was abandoned due to lack of resources - see [GitHub PR #11198](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/pull/11198).

I *presume* that neither of these APIs is subject to the same length limitation as `JavaScriptSerializer`.

Note:

- Direct use of NewtonSoft.Json isn't PowerShell-friendly.
- Third-party module [`PSAdvancedJsonCmdlet`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PSAdvancedJsonCmdlet) - which I haven't personally used - describes itself as "Json cmdlets for Windows PowerShell 5.1, backporting from PowerShell 7", so it may be an option for you.

---

<sup>[1] You managed to download your data into a *.NET string*. .NET strings can only comprise about 1+ billion *characters* (16-bit code units), amounting to 2+ billion bytes (the actual string-length limit is close to 1 GB, which is equivalent to `([int]::MaxValue + 1) / 2`). When I create a trivial JSON document (containing a JSON string value only) as a string with the maximum length, `ConvertFrom-Json` *is* able to parse it on my Window 11 machine running Windows PowerShell v5.1.22621.1778 (.NET Framework 4.8.9167.0); *conceivably*, however, *earlier* PowerShell versions had lower `MaxJsonlength` limits:

`('"{0}"' -f ('x' * ([int]::MaxValue / 2 - 32 - 2 - 1)) | ConvertFrom-Json).Length`</sup>

<sup>[2] [Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) decompiled the `Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility.dll` assembly using [ILSpy](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy) and found that `MaxJsonLength` is set to `int.MaxValue` in v5.1, which is a limit that at least a *single* string cannot even reach (see previous footnote).</sup>